# Why one time it works and another give type error?

Tags: python

When i print PlyingCard class object it properly returns string(eg. Ten of Diamonds), but when i read data from file (text file: 9 d\n7 d) and add it to list as objects of this class, but if i want to print an element of this list it shows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>
> "C:/Python34/Zadanka/r10/r10_z11.py", line 51, in 
>       main()    File "C:/Python34/Zadanka/r10/r10_z11.py", line 50, in main
>       print(card[0]) # TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str    File "C:/Python34/Zadanka/r10/r10_z11.py", line 28, in **str**
>
> return str(self.ranks[self.rank] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.

```
class PlayingCard:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.ranks = [None, "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                      "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        self.suits = {"s":"Spades",
                      "d":"Diamonds",
                      "c":"Clubs",
                      "h":"Hearts"}

    def getRank(self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
        return self.suit

    def BJValue(self):
        BJVal = 0
        if 11 > self.rank > 0:
            BJVal =  self.rank
        elif 14 > self.rank > 10:
            BJVal =  10
        return BJVal

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ranks[self.rank] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit])

def readCard(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    cards = []
    for line in infile:
        cards.append(makeCard(line))
    infile.close()
    return cards

def makeCard(infoStr):
    rank, suit = infoStr.split()
    return PlayingCard(rank, suit)

def main():
    filename = "C:\\Python34\\Zadanka\\r11\\cards.txt"

    a = PlayingCard(10, "d")
    print(a) # Ten of Diamonds

    cards = readCard(filename)
    print(cards[0]) # TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
main()
```

Comment: `self.ranks` is a list and you are indexing it using a string, `self.rank`. You need to use an integer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `makeCard` method you're taking a line read from the file and splitting it, the split will split into two strings for the line being read not an integer and a string.

I think the following should do the trick

```
return PlayingCard(int(rank), suit)
```